# expected unqualified-id before '{' token arduino led

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have looked at previous posts and can't find an answer to my question, here is my code:

```
    const int buttonPin3 = 4;   
    const int ledPin3 =  11;      

    int buttonState3 = 0;        

    {
      pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
    }

    {
      buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);


      if (buttonState3 == HIGH) {

        digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
      } else {

        digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
      }
    }
```

This isn't all of my code, but only the part where the error shows up
just before the `buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);` there is a `{` that is where the error shows for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino land, you generally need to provide an `setup` function which is called once when the program starts, and a `loop` function which will be called continuously while the program is running.

Your code appears to be missing the actual function declaration parts, instead opting for code blocks at file level, which causes that exact error:

```
testprog.cpp:6:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
     {
     ^
```

You'll need something like the following to get it to compile:

```
const int buttonPin3 = 4;
const int ledPin3 =  11;

int buttonState3 = 0;

void setup() {                               // << note here
    pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {                                // << and here
    buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
    if (buttonState3 == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
    }
}
```